# Want to track AJAX newsletter signup as Google Analytics event

Tags: javascript, ajax, events, google-analytics, newsletter

I need to track newsletter signups as events in Google Analytics.
Where do I place the event tracking code? I know I have to place it where the "successful signup" validation is, but I don't know what part of the code further below does the validation.

This is my GA event tracking code:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Newsletter', 'Suscribe to Newsletter', 'Newsletter Form', 0, false]);
```

Here's the newsletter signup form:

```
<form action="http://www.somesite.com/index.php/newsletter/subscriber/new/"  method="post" id="newsletter-validate-detail">
<div class="block-content">
<div class="input-box">
<input type="text" name="email" id="newsletter" title="Subscribe to Newsletter" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" />
</div>
<div class="actions">
<button type="submit" title="Subscribe" class="button"><span><span>Send</span></span></button>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

And here's the javascript for the newsletter:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var newsletterSubscriberFormDetail = new VarienForm('newsletter-validate-detail');
Varien.newsletterForm = Class.create();
Varien.newsletterForm.prototype = {
initialize : function(form, field, emptyText){
this.form = $(form);
this.field = $(field);
this.emptyText = emptyText;
Event.observe(this.form, 'submit', this.submit.bind(this));
Event.observe(this.field, 'focus', this.focus.bind(this));
Event.observe(this.field, 'blur', this.blur.bind(this));
this.blur();
},
submit : function(event){
if (this.field.value == this.emptyText || this.field.value == ''){
Event.stop(event);
return false;
}
return true;
},
focus : function(event){
if(this.field.value==this.emptyText){
this.field.value='';
}
},
blur : function(event){
if(this.field.value==''){
this.field.value=this.emptyText;
}
}
}
var newsletterForm = new Varien.newsletterForm('newsletter-validate-detail',
'newsletter', 'Get the latest news');                                    
//]]>
</script>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should go into the submit function which does the validation (what there is of it):

```
submit : function(event){
if (this.field.value == this.emptyText || this.field.value == ''){
    // does not validate so submit event is aborted
    Event.stop(event);
    return false; 
}
    //validates so it's reasonably safe to sent the event
    gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Newsletter', 'Suscribe to Newsletter', 'Newsletter Form', 0, false]); 
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply to my question.